# Why does IIS 8.0 identify itself as 7.5 via WMI?

Tags: windows-8, iis-8

My web application's installer does some configuration via WMI, and in order to handle different versions will ask IIS for its version with code like:

```
DirectoryEntry folderRoot = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/Info");
Version iisVersion = new Version((int)folderRoot.InvokeGet("MajorIIsVersionNumber"), (int)folderRoot.InvokeGet("MinorIIsVersionNumber"));
```

Server 2012 and Windows 8 both return 7.5 for this, even though the official version is 8.0.  This wouldn't be so much of a problem, except that this is the same version that windows 2008 reports.  Why is this, and is there a better resolution than checking the OS version?

Comment: Quite possibly for the same reason that Win7 reports that it is Windows version 6.1 (type 'ver' at a command prompt) Because the product 'name' doesn't actually reflect the product version. It did during days of Dos and upto Win 3.11 - NT broke the naming convention since the was no version number in the name.

Comment: You're right, reporting something unexpected via the API isn't a problem in and of itself.  I've updated the question to point out that this is the same identifier that was reported by a previous version.  That's what makes it a problem.

Comment: I can only speculate (I don't use IIS or WMI) - But is it possible to check for the existence of an interface? If so, I'd check for the existence of IWebSocketContext.